# How to customize breadcrumbs in Django REST Framework Browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Currently the Browsable API seems to derive the breadcrumbs from the classname of my views. However I am using nested resources for my API so I can get Breadcrumbs like:

Root / User List / User Detail / User Invite List / User Invite Detail

However the fact that the 'User Invite'-views show User again is pretty redundant. I would rather have that their breadcrumbs would just be 'Invite List' and 'Invite Detail'.

Now the most obvious solution would ofcourse be to just rename the view classes but that is not an option for me since I also have the classes ChatInviteList and ChatInviteDetail that share the same problem. So I can't name both of them InviteDetail and InviteList.

Is there a way to customize these breadcrumbs in another way? For example by setting some variable in the view class or something. I tried searching the docs but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a template called `'rest_framework/api.html'` ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing)) that extends `'rest_framework/base.html'` in which you override the `breadcrumbs` block. For guidance, the [original block](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html#L58) looks:

```
{% block breadcrumbs %}
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    {% for breadcrumb_name, breadcrumb_url in breadcrumblist %}
      {% if forloop.last %}
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ breadcrumb_url }}">{{ breadcrumb_name }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb_url }}">{{ breadcrumb_name }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yeah I did find that but in this case I don't want to override the entire breadcrumbs block. For my goal it would be better to override the breadcrumblist context variable, but I couldn't find where that came from.

Comment: Write a [custom renderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) that subclasses the [BrowsableAPIRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#browsableapirenderer) and override `get_breadcrumbs` ;-)

Comment: Through BrowsableAPIRenderer I could better trace where it derived the names from and eventually found that I could solve my problem by just letting my views override `get_view_name`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: This comment saved hours of hunting through DRF, thank you!